# How to get an array to increment with keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, increment, keypress

I need to increment my array with a keypress.  I can get the first element of the array to display but can't get the other elements of the array to display when i press another key.

I've used an alert to get a message to display with a keypress and can get the first element in the array to display but can't get the other elements of the array to display when I press the key again.

```
function display_phrase() {
  var arrayPhrase = ['Relax!', 'Dont Do It!', 'Chill!', 'Take It Easy!', 'Do It!', 'Panic!', 'Beat It!','Forget About It!','Wooooo!','Oh Bother!'];   
  var arrayCounter = 0;
  var arrayPosition = (arrayCounter % arrayPhrase.length);

  $("#display_phrase").html("<h1>" +arrayPhrase[arrayPosition] +".</h1>");
}

var arrayCounter = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').keypress(function() {
    display_phrase();
    arrayCounter++;
  });
});
```

Comment: Nothing to do with Java, and so I've deleted the question tag. Rather it looks to be JavaScript related, and so I've added that tag. No sense attracting the wrong experts to your question.

Comment: `display_phrase` has a local variable `arrayCounter` that takes precedence in the method over the global one.  Remove it.

Comment: `arrayCounter` is reassigning to `0` in `display_phrase`. Raise the scope on `arrayCounter` to above the `display_phrase` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your version, `display_phrase` masks the global `arrayCounter` variable with a local variable of the same name. To fix it, remove the local `var arrayCounter = ...` and keep the declaration in a higher scope.

For example:

```
var arrayPhrase = ['Relax!', 'Dont Do It!', 'Chill!', 'Take It Easy!', 'Do It!', 'Panic!', 'Beat It!','Forget About It!','Wooooo!','Oh Bother!'];   
var arrayCounter = 0;

function display_phrase() {
    var arrayPosition = (arrayCounter % arrayPhrase.length);

    $("#display_phrase").html("<h1>" +arrayPhrase[arrayPosition] +".</h1>");
}

...
```

Comment: The variable inside the method does not reset it.  It is a completely different variable due to the usage of `var`

Comment: Right, but it's masking the global variable. So that the usage in `arrayPosition` always references the local one with a value of 0.

Comment: My point was primarily that the usage of "reset" was incorrect.  To reset something infers that it's value is changed.  But it's not in this case.  The global variable is unchanged as a result of the inner variable.

Comment: Yep, you're right. My initial wording was not precise.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `arrayCounter` inside the function.  Since you have a global variable and a local variable with the same name, the local variable takes precedence inside the function.

Simply remove it, and let it use the global one.

```js
function display_phrase() {
  var arrayPhrase = ['Relax!', 'Dont Do It!', 'Chill!', 'Take It Easy!', 'Do It!', 'Panic!', 'Beat It!', 'Forget About It!', 'Wooooo!', 'Oh Bother!'];
  //var arrayCounter = 0;
  var arrayPosition = (arrayCounter % arrayPhrase.length);

  $("#display_phrase").html("<h1>" + arrayPhrase[arrayPosition] + ".</h1>");
}

var arrayCounter = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').keypress(function() {
    display_phrase();
    arrayCounter++;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="display_phrase"></div>
```